# Getting selected checkboxes/radios and text input from dynamically created controls in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a little bit of experience with C# but i'm new to the ASP side of things and I'm working on a survey project that gets questions/answers from an MSSQL server, loads the appropriate control for what type of answer the question requires (checkboxes, radios, dropdown menu, text input), adds each possible answer for the question as a ListItem and then adds the filled controller to the placeholder that sits within the single survey question webpage. On answer submission, the placeholder is refilled with the next question and loads the appropriate controller for the answer type.

I'm currently having a lot of trouble trying to get whatever the user answer is when they click the submit button as I can't get a reference to any of the checkboxes/radios/text inputs to see which ones are selected or not.

While debugging and stepping through each line and watching local variables change to see what's going on, [this seems to be the hierarchy of the inserted answers at the time they are all added to the placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3JrX.jpg).

I've tried using a forEach loop inside the submitButton (among other things, left it in the code example below) method to check all the items but can't seem to access it at all.. after various tests it seems the answers are destroyed the second the submitButton is pressed and before anything in the submitButton method can run, so how on earth do I get the users answers upon them submitting?

Question.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ....



                else if (questionType == 2) //checkbox 
                {
                    CheckBoxQuestionController checkBoxController = (CheckBoxQuestionController)LoadControl("~/CheckBoxQuestionController.ascx");

                    checkBoxController.ID = "checkBoxQuestionController";
                    checkBoxController.QuestionLabel.Text = questionText;

                    SqlCommand optionCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM answerOptionTable WHERE answerOptionTable.q_Id = " + currentQuestion, connection);

                    //run command
                    SqlDataReader optionReader = optionCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    //loop through all results
                    while (optionReader.Read())
                    {
                        ListItem item = new ListItem(optionReader["answerText"].ToString(), optionReader["a_Id"].ToString());
                        int currentAnswerId = Convert.ToInt32(optionReader["a_Id"]);

                        checkBoxController.QuestionCheckBoxList.Items.Add(item); //add answer to list
                    }

                    QuestionPlaceholder.Controls.Add(checkBoxController);

                }


            //other questionType checking here

            connection.Close();
    }

protected void SubmitButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //template.Items.
        Control resultControl = FindControl("checkBoxQuestionController");

        //test 1
        CheckBoxList resultControl2 = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("checkBoxQuestionController");

        CheckBoxList resultControl3 = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("questionCheckBoxList"); 

        //test 123213
        CheckBoxList Cbx = (CheckBoxList)QuestionPlaceholder.FindControl("checkBoxQuestionController");

        //test 2
        //for (int i = 0; i < QuestionPlaceholder.Controls.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    if (QuestionPlaceholder.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(CheckBoxList))
        //    {
        //        CheckBoxList myList = QuestionPlaceholder.Controls[i].GetType();
        //    }
        //}

        //test 3
        //foreach (ListItem cbList in QuestionPlaceholder.Controls.("checkBoxQuestionController")
        //{
        //    if (cbList.Selected)
        //    {

        //    }
        //}
        //test 4
        //foreach (ListItem cb in QuestionPlaceholder.Controls.OfType<ListItem>())
        //{
        //    if (cb != null)
        //    {

        //    }
        //}

        int count = 0;

        List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem item in debugList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
            Response.Redirect("Question.aspx");
    }
```

CheckBoxQuestionController.ascx.cs

```
public partial class CheckBoxQuestionController : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    //Getters and setters
    public Label QuestionLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return questionLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            questionLabel = value;
        }
    }


    public CheckBoxList QuestionCheckBoxList
    {
        get
        {
            return questionCheckBoxList;
        }
        set
        {
            questionCheckBoxList = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

CheckBoxQuestionController.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CheckBoxQuestionController.ascx.cs" Inherits="Survey_Prototype.CheckBoxQuestionController" %>

    <div class="bodyTitle">
        <asp:Label ID="questionLabel" runat="server" Text="LabelText"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="answerOptionContainer">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="questionCheckBoxList" runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you don't directly use a checkboxlist control but use an own control

when you use your own control, the viewstate should be handled by yourself, otherwise the sub control will be gone after you postback

in your case, in question.aspx.cs you accessed the UC's controls sets, and modified it, but when the page postback, all sub controls you added into it will be gone because the viewstate is applied before the sub controls are created, so actually the user selections will be lost

you should put all modification code to controls into following overridden method, don't remove the base one

then your child control (here it is QuestionCheckBoxList) will be generated before the ViewState gets applied, then your user selection will be kept and you can use whatever method to go through the options to see which are selected

```
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
```